# How can I partition a set of nodes in a Neo4j graph data base into m separate clusters

Tags: algorithm, neo4j, cypher, cluster-analysis, partitioning

In my problem I have n nodes.  Each node is related to every other node by a similarity function S(A,B) for any two nodes A and B.  The relationship is "Is Similar To" and a property of this relationship is the similarity -- S(A,B).  I want to produce m clusters of nodes (partition the nodes into m equal size sets) so that:

- Each node belongs to one and only one cluster, and
- The clusters are all the same size (some can vary by 1 from others if
  n Mod m <> 0)

Then if AVG(C) is the average similarity between every pair of nodes in Cluster C, then I want the average "similarity" of the Average Similarity of all the Clusters to be as small as possible and still meet the two conditions above.  I am trying to figure out how I would do this with Cypher.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely at least NP hard.

So you won't find any algorithm to find the best solution in acceptable time on larger graphs. It's likely that the only known exact algorithms ware not much better than trying out all combinations.

Comment: That is what I was afraid of, but I thought I would reach out and see if anyone had a better idea.